# Sails.js mongodb connection

Tags: javascript, mongodb, sails.js

I've been trying to dockerize my sails.js and mongodb application. Whenever I run docker-compose up, the database connection is refused.

The following error is thrown:

> Failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect [MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017]. at the same time my mongodb image is listening on the port.

My docker-compose file is

```
version: '3.5'

services: 
  mongo:

    image: mongo:3.6
    ports:
      - 27017:27017

    volumes: 
      - "./data:/data/db "

  app: 
    build: "."
    container_name: digital_act_database_config
    links: 
      - mongo
    ports: 
      - "1339:1339"
    restart: always
```

How can I establish a communication between these two ports?

Comment: when i try to access the port it can be accessed. as soon as try virtually i mean from dockerized app it gives error.what is diffrent can anyone tell me

Comment: I think rather than connecting to `localhost:27017` you should be connecting to `mongo:27017`. Docker should handle networking-by-name to the other container.